# grunt failing to find task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, protractor

Here is my grunt file, essentially I want to start an HTTP-Server and kick off protractor tests.  I'm guessing my syntax is off??

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  
  grunt.initConfig({

    karma: {
      options: {
        configFile: 'www/test/karma-conf.js'
      },
      unit: {
        singleRun: true
      },
      continuous: {
        background: true
      }
    },

    protractor: {
      options: {
        configFile: "www/test/frontend.conf.js", // Default config file
        // keepAlive: true, // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails.
        noColor: false, // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output.
        // debug: true,
        args: {

        }
      },
      e2e: {
        options: {
          keepAlive: false
        }
      },
      continuous: {
        options: {
          keepAlive: true
        }
      }
    },

    watch: {
      options: {
        livereload: true
      },
      karma: {
        files: ['www/js/**/*.js', 'www/test/unit/*.js'],
        tasks: ['karma:continuous:run']
      }
      ,
      protractor: {
        files: ['www/js/**/*.js', 'www/test/e2e/*.js'],
        tasks: ['protractor:continuous']
      }
    },

    run: {
      mock_server: {
        options: {
          wait: false
        },
        args: ['app/mockApi/apiserver.js']
      }
    },

    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        hostname: 'localhost'
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: 35729,
          open: true,
          base: ['www']
          
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          base: ['www']
        }
      }
    }

  });

  //grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  //grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
  //grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
  //grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-runner');
  //grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-run');

  grunt.registerTask('serve', ['karma:continuous:start', 'run:mock_server', 'connect:livereload', 'watch:karma']);

  grunt.registerTask('unit-test', ['karma:continuous:start', 'watch:karma']);
  
  grunt.registerTask('e2e-test', ['connect:test',  'protractor:continuous', 'watch:protractor']);

  grunt.registerTask('test', ['karma:unit:start', 'connect:test', 'run:mock_server', 'protractor:e2e']);

};
```

All I get when running is the following error :

```
$ grunt e2e-test --verbose
  Initializing
  Command-line options: --verbose

  Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

  Registering Gruntfile tasks.
  Initializing config...OK
  Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
  + e2e-test, serve, test, unit-test

  Running tasks: e2e-test

  Running "e2e-test" task
  Warning: Task "connect:test" not found. Use --force to continue.

  Aborted due to warnings.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to uncomment `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');`

Comment: It turns out that that was the case.. I was confused because those modules had already been installed.  So Thought having those lines was superfluous